# How can I stop messages from printing more than once inside of an if statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to create a hangman game where the user guesses a three-letter word. I have a variable called "guesses". I have my code set up to where if the user doesn't guess a letter that is in the word (chosen from a word list) then I have ++ for guesses. Depending on what guess the user is on, a message pops up saying that the letter is not in the word and they have however many guesses left. But what I noticed is that if a letter is guessed incorrectly, then after if it is guessed correctly, then the previous message still pops up
this is my code
I've tried incorporating a break or return statement, but it just stops it altogether. can anyone please help?

```
function hangManGame() {
  var wordList = ["cat"];
  var guesses = 0;

  var randomWord = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
  while (randomWord) {
    var letterGuessed = readLine("Please guess ONE lowercase letter at a time. ");
    if (letterGuessed == randomWord[0]) {
      println("Congratulations, you guessed a letter correctly!");
    } else if (letterGuessed == randomWord[1]) {
      println("Congratulations, you guessed a letter correctly!");  
    } else if (letterGuessed == randomWord[2]) {
      println("Congratulations, you guessed a letter correctly!");
    } else {
      guesses++;
    }
    
     if (guesses == 1) {
      println("Sorry, that letter is not in the word, you have 2 guesses remaining.");
      add(head);
      add(body);
    }
     if (guesses == 2) {
      println("Sorry, that letter is not in the word, you have 1 guess remaining.");
      add(leftArm);
      add(rightArm);
        
    }
    if (guesses == 3) {
      println("Sorry, that letter is not in the word, you have 0 guesses remaining.");
      add(leftLeg);
      add(rightLeg);
    break;
    }
    
    
   }
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243781/discussion-on-question-by-bisulfate-how-can-i-stop-messages-from-printing-more-t).

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has some major flaws:

1. It only works for 3 letter words
2. You duplicate your code multiple times
3. It also doesn't work at all you can type in letter "c" three times in a row and win.

this is my solution you can adapt it to your "needs" as I provided in comments

```js
// the responseArray is to simulate the readLines as I wanted to run the code in the browser console
function hangManGame(word, tries = 3, responseArray = ['c', 'a', 't']) {
  // getting the first from array instead of reading user input
  while (responseArray.length > 0 && tries > 0) {
    const guessedLetter = responseArray.shift()
    // make it generic instead of having to rewrite the if over and over
    // if the word contains our letter
    if (word.indexOf(guessedLetter) != -1) {
      console.log(`correct guess: ${guessedLetter}`)
    } else {
      console.log(`Wrong latter: ${guessedLetter} tries remaining ${--tries}`)
    }
  }
}

hangManGame('cat', 3, ['x', 'a', 'f', 'g'])
```

AS provided in comments the response array is only there to simulate your user inputs so just remove it and instead of assigning `guessedLetter` variable to `responseArray.shift()` assign it to `readLine()`. If you have any questions add them in comment ;)

Still you should probably add a way for person to see the word they typing as in true hangman which would look something like this

```js
// the responseArray is to simulate the readLines as I wanted to run the code in the browser console
function hangManGame(word, tries = 3, responseArray = ['c', 'a', 't']) {
  const correctLetters = [];
  // getting the first from array instead of reading user input
  while (responseArray.length > 0 && tries > 0) {
    const guessedLetter = responseArray.shift()
    // make it generic instead of having to rewrite the if over and over
    // if the word contains our letter
    if (word.indexOf(guessedLetter) != -1) {
      correctLetters.push(guessedLetter)
      console.log(`correct guess: ${guessedLetter}`)
      console.log(Array.from(word).map(letter => {
        return correctLetters.some(correctLetter => correctLetter === letter) ? letter : "_"
      }))
    } else {
      console.log(`Wrong latter: ${guessedLetter} tries remaining ${--tries}`)
    }
  }
}

hangManGame('cat', 3, ['x', 'a', 'c', 'g'])
```